# Passing SPI data from C to CPP Teensy 3.5

Tags: c++, c, pointers, void

I am struggling at the moment to integrate some 3rd party code into a project I’m working on. The 3rd parties code is written in C and my main code is CPP. I’m struggling with the pointer references and I’ve still a lot to learn regarding this.

I am running the code on a Teensy 3.5 board (Arduino like) and linking up to the 3rd party’s product via SPI. I’m using Platform IO within Visual Studio Code.
In the 3rd party code they have packaged all the data up for me and it should be a simple case of just clocking the bytes in & out over the SPI bus.

The area I’m struggling with is they are using void pointers to the Tx & Rx data blocks. I’m also not sure where or how to write the received data back to the pointer.

I've attached some code below at my initial attempts but welcome any assistance anyone could offer.

**Main.cpp**

```
SPISettings SPIconfig(1000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0);

extern "C" void TNSY_SPI_TransmitReceive(uint8_t *dataTx, uint8_t *dataRx, uint16_t len)  {
   Serial.print("TNSY_SPI_TransmitReceive: ");
   SPI.beginTransaction(SPIconfig);
   digitalWrite(SLAVESELECT,LOW);
   delayMicroseconds(1);
   for (uint16_t i = 0; i < len; i++)  {
      *dataRx = SPI.transfer(*dataTx);       // send the data, while storing the received data
      dataTx++;                              // increment the pointer to the next value
      dataRx++;                              // increment the poitner to the next space for RXdata
      }
   digitalWrite(SLAVESELECT,HIGH);
   delayMicroseconds(1);
   SPI.endTransaction();  
}
```

**3rd Party's C**

```
static SpiDataReceivedCbfType pnDataReadyCbf;
void SpiRegDataReceived(SpiDataReceivedCbfType pnDataReceived  )
{
   pnDataReadyCbf = pnDataReceived;
}

void SpiSendReceive( void* pxSendDataBuffer, void* pxReceiveDataBuffer, UINT16 iLength )
{
   TNSY_SPI_TransmitReceive(pxSendDataBuffer, pxReceiveDataBuffer, iLength);
   pnDataReadyCbf();
}
```

Comment: Hi, it would be useful if you can share any errors you are facing/including compilation

Comment: Hi, I'm not seeing any errors as such, it compiles and runs. I'm just not seeing the data flow so wanted to check i've understood the principles correctly

Comment: Runs and works as intended?

Comment: i'm not sure if i'm passing the data in the pointer or passing the actual address of the pointer. like i said im a bit shaky on pointers and the void pointer has thrown me a little

Comment: @Jef0778 Can you elaborate what you mean when you say you are not seeing the data flow? Are you probing the bus and not seeing clocks/data?

Comment: The data I'm passing to the SPI using the above code doesn't seem to have an effect on the device I've connected to. I've used a DS1054 scope looking at the SPI channels and the data I'm sending seems to be incremented hex values, so i though i might be sending the address of the pointer rather than the value at the pointers address.

Comment: am i using the pointers correctly ?

Comment: So how do you use the 3rd party code? The functions you posted have nothing to do with the code in main.cpp

Comment: when SpiSendReceive() is called in the 3rd party's code it calls the TNSY_SPI_TransmitReceive() in the main code..